# Create custom entity in CiviCRM with its UI form for data entry?

Tags: civicrm-entity, workflow

I want to create new custom entity in the Drupal-CiviCRM with its form from where user can data. In my case I want to have something like : User can register new application for keeping dangerous animal. It will then initiate workflow which will forward the application for its approval/decline process to admin.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to use the CiviCRM Webform Integration module and start a case in CiviCRM when an application form is submitted?

Comment: Yes. It similar to that. Once I submit the details on the form, the admin users can able to approve / decline the workflow which will also send email to the user who has submitted the details. Can you guide me how to achieve this?

Comment: Only if you do it the CiviCRM Webform Integration module way :-) Otherwise I would not know.